# npm ERR! Exit status 1 when running script

Tags: angular9, npm-scripts

I am getting an error when I run this command in npm, why is that?

```
"testserver1": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage",
```

I run it with

```
npm run testserver1
```

```
npm ERR!  testserver1: `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```